# Eclipse - Android - simple code doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

First, sorry for the (supposed) stupid question.

This code doesn't work (see below the error message on the tablet and the LogCat)

What's wrong?

I work on Eclipse ADT and try simply to create a button that launch a progress bar. :op

I use a cheap chinese Dalvik tablet to run the app.

```
 import ...
 public class Coach extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v("comment","create");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coach);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            }

        Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        Log.v("comment","onClickListener");     
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("comment","onClick");
                  int jumpTime = 0;
                  int totalProgressTime = 100;
                  while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime){
                     try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                        jumpTime += 5;
                        progressBar.incrementProgressBy(jumpTime);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I have this message on the tablet "the app "..." has stopped".

The LogCat:

> 12-31 01:43:22.206: E/Trace(2947): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.336: V/comment(2947): create
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.506: V/comment(2947): onClickListener
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.506: D/AndroidRuntime(2947): Shutting down VM
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.506: W/dalvikvm(2947): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x416f2930)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.NicolasDoyen.redstarcoach/com.NicolasDoyen.redstarcoach.Coach}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-31
>   01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   com.NicolasDoyen.redstarcoach.Coach.onCreate(Coach.java:34)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>
> 12-31 01:43:22.516: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):   ... 11 more

Here is the xml definition of my very simple UI:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.NicolasDoyen.redstarcoach.Coach$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:text="start" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If i turn the lines

> start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

and below as comment, there is no error. So i guess the error is somewhere there...

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_. What happens exactly?

Comment: Please post your logcat trace

Comment: which one is the error line? your lines in the program are not going to coincide with what you posted since you skipped some imports

Comment: You are sleeping in the UI thread, which you shouldn't do.  You need to use a worker to wait and update the progress bar.

Comment: Please find the answers in the edited body. And already thanks for your time.

Comment: Your error is on line 34 of your code (com.NicolasDoyen.redstarcoach.Coach.onCreate(Coach.java:34)). My guess would be you don't have the Button with the name "start" on your Activity Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start); which causes the error when trying to assign an onClick event

Comment: Thanks DigCamara. As you can see at the end of the edited body, i have a start button with the right definition (as far as i know).

Comment: @DigCamara: I define the progressBar in the line 32: final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2); --- and FYI, the line 34 is: start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Well, the only thing on that line that could cause a NPE is the start variable. So my guess would be that even though you think you have the correct reference, you actually don't. Do you have multiple layout definitions for different devices?

Comment: I noticed something: the xml code above is in a file named _fragment_coach.xml_. In my previous project, the file was named _activity_previousproject.xml_. In the current project, there is a _activity_coach.xml_, but it includes something else... Do you smell a smelly smell from that?

Comment: change your setContentView call to setContentView(R.layout.fragment_coach);

Comment: @samgak: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be the solution (i tried but failed > lots of error lines in the LogCat). Sinds the app run correctly whitout the lines 34 and below (showing a button and a progress bar on the tablet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I redefined my UI in activity_coach.xml instead of fragment_coach.xml. Aaaand, it works... Don't know why and where this fragment stuff comes from. But, anyway, it works...